# R summarize group_by result

Tags: r

I have a data "dat_KOR14_16"

why this function have a different output?

I'm struggling with incorrect results.

```
a <-summarize(group_by(dat_KOR14_16,SIGUN,LCLASSNAME,MCLASSNAME),AVG_PRICE=mean(AVG_
PRICE))

a <- summarize(group_by(a,LCLASSNAME,MCLASSNAME),AVG_PRICE=mean(AVG_PRICE))
a
# A tibble: 505 x 3
# Groups:   LCLASSNAME [?]
   LCLASSNAME MCLASSNAME  AVG_PRICE
        <chr>      <chr>      <dbl>
 1       농업       가랏   4187.569
 2       농업   가오리포 101000.000
 3       농업   가죽나물   9875.621
 4       농업       가지   9246.471
 5       농업 가지나무순   5815.374
 6       농업     갈치포  56231.905
 7       농업       감귤  12722.828
 8       농업       감자  14765.841
 9       농업       감초  34916.667
10       농업         갓   5183.005
# ... with 495 more rows
> a <-summarize(group_by(dat_KOR14_16,LCLASSNAME,MCLASSNAME),AVG_PRICE=mean(AVG_PRICE))
> a
# A tibble: 505 x 3
# Groups:   LCLASSNAME [?]
   LCLASSNAME MCLASSNAME  AVG_PRICE
        <chr>      <chr>      <dbl>
 1       농업       가랏   3938.466
 2       농업   가오리포 101000.000
 3       농업   가죽나물   8957.503
 4       농업       가지  10400.846
 5       농업 가지나무순   2005.054
 6       농업     갈치포  40501.212
 7       농업       감귤  12928.582
 8       농업       감자  16416.196
 9       농업       감초  41642.857
10       농업         갓   7333.404
# ... with 495 more rows
```

I have to make average_Price by "MCLASSNAME" correctly

Orgin data Like this,

```
DATES AVG_PRICE LCLASSNAME MCLASSNAME      SIDO     SIGUN
1 20140425     30420       농업     양상추   서울   중구
```

I've made 2dimension by SIGUN and get average value.

but it have a uncorrect values

So I need to find out what is matter about using summarize function.

```
No  LCLASSNAME  MCLASSNAME  TOTAL   SIDO1   SIGUN1  SIGUN2  SIGUN3  SIGUN4  SIGUN5  SIGUN6  SIGUN7  SIGUN8  SIGUN9  SIGUN10 SIGUN11 SIGUN12 SIGUN13 SIGUN14 SIGUN15 SIGUN16 SIGUN17 SIGUN18
1       농업   가죽나물  함양군    3393.333  익산시        7550      0      0      0  24025   3000      0   4000      0   7550      0      0
2       농업   가죽나물  함양군    3393.333  남원시       24025      0      0      0  24025   3000      0   4000      0   7550      0      0
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: It is better to use `%>%` to make the code clear.  You have included `LCLASSNAME` also in `group_by`

Comment: your code is a bit all over the place. Can you give us `dput()` of your df? That way we can assess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As akrun said, its easier if you the pipe operator(%>%).

The pipe operator (%>%) pass the argument to the next function.I found this example in the datacamp site, for you to learn what the %>% does.
These 2 lines of code do the same:

```
pi %>% sin %>% cos

cos(sin(pi))
```

I rewrite your code, but i think with what i wrote you can see the difference.

```
a <- dat_KOR14_16 %>% 
        group_by(SIGUN,LCLASSNAME,MCLASSNAME) %>% 
          summarize(AVG_PRICE=mean(AVG_PRICE))
a <- a %>% 
        group_by(LCLASSNAME,MCLASSNAME) %>% 
            summarize(AVG_PRICE=mean(AVG_PRICE))

a <- dat_KOR14_16 %>% 
        group_by(LCLASSNAME,MCLASSNAME) %>% 
            summarize(AVG_PRICE=mean(AVG_PRICE))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for or what variables you need to group on, but I would say somewhere near..

```
a <- dat_KOR14_16 %>% 
            group_by(MCLASSNAME) %>%
            summarise(new_avg_price = mean(AVG_PRICE))
```